# filtering records with left outer join in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using following SQL left outer join to get data:

```
SELECT resource_name, un_diary_apps.date_app_start, un_diary_apps.date_app_end
FROM un_diary_resources
LEFT OUTER JOIN un_diary_apps
    ON resource_sequence = un_diary_resources.sequence
WHERE un_diary_apps.date_app_start BETWEEN '2014-09-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-24 23:59:59'
```

and out put is [image]

When I apply date range it shows records in those dates. I want all resource_name even if they have appointments in those date ranges or not.

Comment: Left join seems to be the correct strategy to always get all `resource_name` records in your result set, and the screen capture seems to be on the right track.  What is your question then?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you specify a value from the right side of a `left join` in a `WHERE` `clause` (which is not `NULL`), you necessarily eliminate all of the `NULL` values and it essentially becomes an `inner join.`

USE `AND` clause instead of `WHERE`

```
select resource_name,un_diary_apps.date_app_start,un_diary_apps.date_app_end from un_diary_resources 
left outer join un_diary_apps 
on (resource_sequence = un_diary_resources.sequence
AND un_diary_apps.date_app_start BETWEEN '2014-09-24 00:00:00'
AND '2014-09-24 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.resource_name, apps.date_app_start, apps.date_app_end
FROM un_diary_resources r
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.resource_sequence, a.date_app_start, a.date_app_end 
    FROM un_diary_apps a
    WHERE a.date_app_start BETWEEN '2014-09-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-24 23:59:59'
) AS apps
ON r.sequence = apps.resource_sequence
```